# Django raw Sql Join (return only first model)

Tags: python, mysql, django, join

I have gone through all the result for **Raw Django query** but still not able to get how will i retrieve d**ata of both table with key value pair**. Please check the two different approaches that i have tried :

```
result = TblSchedule.objects.raw("SELECT tbl_schedule.id, tbl_user.fname AS name from tbl_schedule join tbl_user using (id)")
data = serializers.serialize("json", result)
    result = json.loads(data)
```

this gives me object for the TblSchedule but no data for user table, i need the data from both tables. 
Second approach was using cursror:

```
cursor.execute("select tbluser.fname from tbl_schedule tblsch inner join tbl_user tbluser on tblsch.user_id=tbluser.id where tblsch.doctor_id = %s", [doctorId])
check =[]
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row is not None:
   row = cursor.fetchone()
   check = cursor.fetchone()
return Response(check)
```

this result in return only the name but no key.
I need the key value pair for the join (without having the foreigne key relation between them)

Comment: But why do you need a raw query for this?

Comment: you can suggest me other way if you have. i dont have relation of primary to foreigne  key, so suggest me way other then raw query.

Comment: If you look very closely at your question you will find that the information that you added in the comment is not included in the question. in fact the question does not give any idea at all about what your models are like

Comment: I know it is a quite old question. But were able to solve this mystery?